# Why would the VB.NET compiler think an interface isn't implemented when it is?

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, interface, compiler-errors, inotifypropertychanged

### Update

I don't think I was clear enough when I originally posted this quesion.

Take a look at these screenshots.

[image]
([Link to bigger screenshot here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/674358/INotifyPropertyChanged1.jpg))

Notice the portions I've boxed in red. The class displayed here **does** implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but the VB compiler seems to think that the `PropertyChanged` event as declared does not match the signature of `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`.

[image]
([Link to bigger screenshot here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/674358/INotifyPropertyChanged2.jpg))

Here I've selected the offending line of code. Between this and the next screenshot I literally just **cut and paste** the **exact same line** back into the file (i.e., I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>).

[image]
([Link to bigger screenshot here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/674358/INotifyPropertyChanged3.jpg))

Now behold! After cutting and pasting the line back in, the error goes away.

**What is going on here?**

---

### Original question

I have this happen sometimes, particularly with the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in my experience but I have no idea if the problem is limited to that single interface (which would seem bizarre) or not.

Let's say I have some code set up like this. There's an interface with a single event. A class implements that interface. It includes the event.

```
Public Interface INotifyPropertyChanged
    Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler
End Interface

Public Class Person
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged _
    (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    ' more code below '
End Class
```

Every now and then, when I build my project, the compiler will suddenly start acting like the above code is broken. It will report that the `Person` class does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` because it doesn't have a `PropertyChanged` event; or it will say the `PropertyChanged` event can't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` because their signatures don't match.

This is weird enough as it is, but here's the weirdest part: **if I just cut out the line starting with `Event PropertyChanged` and then paste it back in, the error goes away.** The project builds.

Does anybody have any clue what could be going on here?

Comment: Just wanted to update.

I encounter this bug on a regular basis. Many times when I move classes around using cut & paste, the interface's events "break": I get a "x must implement" and a "y cannot implement..." at the same time. I cut and pase again and it all goes well.

Sometimes I get the same bug when I use the "Move type to file" feature of devXpress' CodeRush tool. Sometimes I get other related phenomena, such as phantom classes which go away once building the project again. 

Bugs, i tell ya :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works fine for me (Visual Studio 2008), you must be encountering some bug.

Anyhow, you can also implement it this way:

```
Public Class Person
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

End Class
```

Comment: I think you're right; it's a bug. I guess I'll report it to the VB.NET folks at MS.

Comment: Is this reported on Microsoft Connect? If so, what's the link? I'd like to upvote it because this happens to us all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the event `Public`

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault for not copying and pasting boilerplate code. The event is `Public` in the class. Like I said, cutting and pasting the line right back in makes the error go away (and the project builds).